# Make all the fields in a form not required

Tags: forms

I know that, when I want to run off the `#require` property of a field in `hook_form_alter()`, I just need to set `#require` property of a specific field to `FALSE`.

How can I remove the `#required` property  of all the required fields? I want to make the fields not required when the user has a specific role.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're ok with the risks that this might well pose to the integrity of your content you could probably use a simple recursive script like the following in a form alter function:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'myform_name') {
    $form['#after_build'][] = '_MYMODULE_remove_required';
  }
}

function _MYMODULE_remove_required(&$element) {
  $element['#required'] = FALSE;

  foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
    _MYMODULE_remove_required($element[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: good solution Clive, what is your idea about below answer?

Comment: Putting it in `#after_build` is probably a good idea, but your recursive function isn't recursing at the moment!

Comment: Notice that the `#after_build` function is required to return the element it gets as argument, which is not passed as reference. See [system_check_directory()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_check_directory/7), used in [system.admin.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/7).

Comment: +1 just for showing use of element_children(), really useful, and helped me disable all form elements easily

Comment: In Drupal 8, you'll use ``Element::children`` instead of `element_children`.

Answer (score 3):

```
   function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     if ($form_id == 'myform_name') {
       if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles) {
         $form['#after_build'][] ='mymodule_recursive_unrequired';
       }
     }
   }

   function mymodule_reqursive_unrequired($element) {
     foreach (element_children($element) as $name) {
       $element[$name]['#required'] = FALSE;
     }

     return $element;
   }
```

I didn't test it yet; it is just an idea.

Comment: The `#after_build` functions are required to return the element it gets as argument, which is not passed as reference. See [system_check_directory()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_check_directory/7), which is the `#after_build` function used in [system.admin.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.admin.inc/7).

Comment: @kiamlaluno , I got this idea from a module disable all form element and worked for me.hoever thanks for antention.

Comment: You just need to remove the _&_ in `function mymodule_reqursive_unrequired(&$element)`, and then is all fine. I would rather accept your answer, as at least it correctly returns `$element`.

Answer (score 2):

I used this answer and thought I'd share some improvements:

As above, add the following function as an #after_build callback for the appropriate users.

```
/**
 * Removes "required" from all form elements.
 * Use at your own risk.
 * Use:  in a _form_alter function, $form['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_remove_required';
 * @param array $element
 * @param array $form_state
 * @param int $depth
 * @return mixed
 */
function MYMODULE_remove_required($element, &$form_state, $depth=0) {
  if ( $depth > 6 ) return $element; // put a limit on recursion
  if ( !empty($element['#required']) ) $element['#required'] = FALSE;
  // only iterate over children for likely elements
  if ( empty($element['#type']) || !in_array($element['#type'], array('radios','checkboxes')) ) {
    foreach ( element_children($element) as $name ) {
      $element[$name] = MYMODULE_remove_required($element[$name], $form_state, $depth+1);
    }
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: This is the only one I could get to work

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Required by role](https://www.drupal.org/project/required_by_role) module.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
The solution I posted seems to be a bad idea.
When you reset the $form_state['values'] array, what is actually happening is that you are removing the form token id. You could get the same effect by adding:

```
$form_state['values']['form_token'] = false;
```

This seems like a bad idea especially if you have multiple content editors. This also creates a Drupal error message:

```
The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page.
```

ISSUE: I have an issue with field_collections (embedded). I am unable to add/remove items.

This worked perfectly:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/56350/72908

Basically you just need to reset the $form_state['values'] array in your #after_build function.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */
    function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      if ($form['type']['#value'] == 'YOUR FORM TYPE') {
        $form['#after_build'][] = 'custom_function_after_build';
      }
    }

    function custom_function_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
      $form_state['values'] = array();
      return $form;
    }
```