# How to disable required fields in form?

Tags: 7, forms

I am building a multi-step form.  For one of the steps, I have some required fields.  When the user goes back, I'm skipping the validation, but it gets hung up on my required fields.  Is there a way to disable or ignore my required fields so my user can go back a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use

[#limit_validation_errors](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#limit_validation_errors)

> Used by: button, image_button, submit
>
> Description: Provides an array of sections which are parts of
>   `$form_state['values']` which should be validated, implying that
>   sections which are not listed should not be validated.
>
> This is normally used in multistep forms in the case of a "back" button, for
>   example, where `'#limit_validation_errors' => array()` would mean not to
>   validate anything as form values on the current page are to be
>   discarded anyway.
>
> `#limit_validation_errors` does not have any effect if `#submit` is not set. More discussion is in the form_set_error() documentation.
>
> Values: array indicating sections of the `$form_state['values']` which should be validated.